# JQ command to retrieve just the titles

Tags: jq

I have this json file:

```
"[{\"id\":188457,\"title\":\"Painted Dragon Tea Mug with Lid\",\"slug\":\"painted-dragon-tea-mug-with-lid\",\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/thievemedia.imgix.net\\\/2018\\\/09\\\/painted-dragon-tea-mug-with-lid-featured-1.jpg\",\"full_image_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.amazonaws.com\\\/thieve-media\\\/wp-content\\\/uploads\\\/2018\\\/09\\\/painted-dragon-tea-mug-with-lid-featured-1.jpg\",\"large_image_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.amazonaws.com\\\/thieve-media\\\/wp-content\\\/uploads\\\/2018\\\/09\\\/painted-dragon-tea-mug-with-lid-featured-1.jpg\",\"medium_image_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s3.amazonaws.com\\\/thieve-media\\\/wp-content\\\/uploads\\\/2018\\\/09\\\/painted-dragon-tea-mug-with-lid-featured-1.jpg\",\"original_price\":\"19.78\",\"price\":\"13.65\",\"discount\":\"30.99\",\"rating\":\"4.7\",\"total_orders\":\"10\",\"promotion_url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/api.thieve.co\\\/view?id=MzI4NTk0Njg0MDE=\",\"product_like_count\":\"100\",\"product_user_likes\"}]
```

How can I extract only the titles with jq?

Comment: That's not valid JSON -- it is a JS string containing escape sequences, so you'll first have to remove those escapes with eg. `sed 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/\\\(.\)/\1/g'`

Answer (score 2):

The query `'.[] | {title}'` will give you just the title elements (but note that your sample document seems to be malformed), assuming your document is in a file called `data.json`:

```
$ jq '.[] | {title}' data.json
{
    "title": "Painted Dragon Tea Mug with Lid"
}
```

The first part of the query, `'.[]'`, returns each object in the top-level array, and these are then sent to the second part, using the `|` operator. The second part of the query, `{title}`, simply extracts the "title" element from the object.

If you want just the title, as a string, without wrapping the results in a JSON object, use this instead:

```
$ jq '.[] | .["title"]' data.json
"Painted Dragon Tea Mug with Lid"
```

The `jq` [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) offers a good overview of the query language.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The original file is at https://api.thieve.co/wp-json/thieve/v1/products/?category-name=/category/homeware&filter=new&offset=48 but I'm getting an error :(

Comment: You can shorten the expression to `.[].title`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is a JSON string, encoding the actual JSON document, you may use `jq` to decode the string into JSON and then extract the `title` key's value from each of the elements in the top-level array:

```bash
jq -r 'fromjson[]|.title' file
```